# SharePoint 2010: solution/feature upgrade recommended practices

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

this is kind of an open question: I'm trying to define for a team a set of recommended practices for delivering a SharePoint solution in stages. That means, changes will happen at every level (solution, feature, web part, content types, etc).

On your experience, which are the practices that really, really, worked for you guys? For ex. using upgrade custom actions, placing upgrade logic entirely on FeatureUprading event handlers? Or in FeatureActiving handlers and assume features could already exist? Else?

I'm asking because I know of projects that follow The Word on this from many MSDN articles and still, upgrades are kind of nightmarish to manage, and those processes are sometimes difficult to grasp for average devs.

Thanks!

Comment: Anything's gotta be better than how it is in 2007. The word "upgrade" when you're in 2007 makes you reach for the bottle.

Comment: I agree. But, as with everything else in SharePoint, there are lots of choices, hence my question. Thanks.

Comment: I like this question, but I feel like the scope is really... really big. Someone could write a book on this.

Comment: They could, but would they want to relive the nightmares? It'd be like an alcoholic having a relapse.

Answer (score 0):

As no one else has ventured an answer, my current approach is:

1. Use the declarative approach for those cases where it works 100% of the time e.g. NOT content types
2. Fall back to code for the rest
3. Always write the related code so that it can be run multiple times against either the pre- or post-upgrade state